# How to integrate Nedb with electron

Tags: javascript, database, typescript, electron, nedb

I'm making an app in electron and i want to use **Nedb** as its database.

I've tried for a couple of days to get this to work all in vain unfortunately.

I'm using electron with **VueJs**

any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you share any code sample?

Comment: Check this if it helps: https://riptutorial.com/electron/example/32649/connecting-electron-app-with-nedb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example:

https://medium.com/@shivekkhurana/persist-data-in-electron-apps-using-nedb-5fa35500149a

Here is a code sample:

```
// create a file named main/src/db.js
const {app} = require('electron');
const Datastore = require('nedb-promises');
const dbFactory = (fileName) => Datastore.create({
 filename: `${process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev' ? '.' : 
 app.getAppPath('userData')}/data/${fileName}`, 
 timestampData: true,
 autoload: true
});
```